# mailchimp auto pre filled url encoding

Tags: php, html, mailchimp, subscription, url-encoding

how to pre fill my subscription forum with email.for example if some one want to enter his "email" and click "senden" button for subscription, his "Email" should already be there in my subscription forum. down is the urls from website(for embedded subscription forum), code of this embedded widget and subscription forum.

mail chimp subscription forum url: http://boooo.us7.list-manage.com/subscribe?u=2e01f07a729f6f76a41a34ca5&id=66efb8b1bb

website url: www.boooo.com

code:

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->

<div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="//eepurl.com/-xxxx" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate="">
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
            <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder=" E-Mail Adresse" required="" /> 
            <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->

            <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;">
                <input type="text" name="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxx" tabindex="-1" value="" />
            </div>

            <div class="clear">
                <input type="submit" value="senden" name="senden" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code you have used so far.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not mentioning the code it was my first question and didn't notice to put 4 spaces for the code.

I solved it by adding "&email=value" in the last of my url.

```
    <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->

    <div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="http://boooo.us7.list-manage.com/subscribe?u=2e01f07a729f6f76a41a34ca5&id=66efb8b1bb&email=value" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name=
    "mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate="">
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
            <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder=" E-Mail Adresse" required="@" /> 
            <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->

            <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;">
                <input type="text" name="e01f07a729f76a41a34ca5_66efb8" tabindex="-1" value="" />
            </div>

            <div class="clear">
                <input type="submit" value="senden" name="senden" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<!--End mc_embed_signup  mce-EMAIL mc4wp_email //eepurl.com/-Mi4r
-->
```

Comment: if this answered your question you can select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $_POST variable on your backend form for this.

The first form:

```
<form action="subscription.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="first_email">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The subscription form:

```
<form action="mailchimp.php">
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['first_email']; ?>"
....
```

For more info:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is go to that mailchimp signup page and prefill the email, this link seems to work:

https://boooo.us7.list-manage.com/subscribe?u=2e01f07a729f6f76a41a34ca5&id=66efb8b1bb&MERGE0=foobar@foobar.com

If you need a form, try

```
<!-- Mailchimp Signup Form -->

<form 
  action="https://boooo.us7.list-manage.com/subscribe?u=2e01f07a729f6f76a41a34ca5&id=66efb8b1bb" 
  method="post" target="_blank">
  <input type="email" name="MERGE0" placeholder="Your e-mail">
  <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
</form>

<!--End  Mailchimp Signup Form -->
```